# Finding win/loss record of all teams in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the win/loss record of each team in my database. I feel that I am close but I cant seem to get the final step.

The table looks something like this:

```
GameID | TeamAID | TeamBID | Winner
-----------------------------------
  1         1         2        1
  2         3         5        3
 ...       ...       ...      ...
```

Link to MySQL Fiddle here with my attempts: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26b00/7

My approach to this problem was to first find the number of games each team played, then to find the number of wins each team had, and finally to subtract wins from games played to get the number of losses.

The query I came up with to find the number of games played is as follow:

```
SELECT Game.TeamAID, TA.Count + TB.Count AS Sum
FROM Game
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TeamAID, COUNT(GameID) AS Count
           FROM Game
           GROUP BY TeamAID) AS TA ON TA.TeamAID = Game.TeamAID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TeamBID, COUNT(GameID) AS Count
           FROM Game
           GROUP BY TeamBID) AS TB ON TB.TeamBID = Game.TeamAID
GROUP BY TeamAID
```

This successfully gives me each team that has played a game as well as the number of games that team played.

Next is when my problem arises.

This is the query I made to give me the number of wins each team had:

```
SELECT Game.TeamAID, TA.Cnt + TB.Cnt AS Sum
FROM Game
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TeamAID, COUNT(GameID) AS Cnt
           FROM Game
           WHERE TeamAID = Winner
           GROUP BY TeamAID
           ORDER BY TeamAID) AS TA ON TA.TeamAID = Game.TeamAID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TeamBID, COUNT(GameID) AS Cnt
           FROM Game
           WHERE TeamBID = Winner
           GROUP BY TeamBID
           ORDER BY TeamBID) AS TB ON TB.TeamBID = Game.TeamAID
GROUP BY TeamAID;
```

The issue this gives me is that it returns null after the join in some cases when a particular team hadn't won any matches while playing as TeamA or TeamB.

Is there a way different way to get the number of games each team won so that I don't get the issue with the result being null? Or better yet is there a simpler solution to my problem that I have overlooked?

I would ultimately like the results to appear something like:

```
TeamID | Wins | Losses
----------------------
  6       18      1
 ...      ...    ...
```

Thanks to Adam V for leading me to find the IFNULL function which has helped me solve my problem.

The solution is as follows:

```
SELECT Game.TeamAID, GP.Sum AS GamesWon, ((TA.CA + TB.CB) - GP.Sum) AS GameLost
FROM Game

LEFT JOIN (SELECT TeamAID, COUNT(GameID) AS CA
           FROM Game
           GROUP BY TeamAID
          ) AS TA ON TA.TeamAID = Game.TeamAID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT TeamBID, COUNT(GameID) AS CB
           FROM Game
           GROUP BY TeamBID
          ) AS TB ON TB.TeamBID = Game.TeamAID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT Game.TeamAID, IFNULL(TA.Cnt,0)  + IFNULL(TB.Cnt,0) AS Sum
           FROM Game
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT TeamAID, COUNT(GameID) AS Cnt
                      FROM Game
                      WHERE TeamAID = Winner
                      GROUP BY TeamAID
                      ORDER BY TeamAID
                     ) AS TA ON TA.TeamAID = Game.TeamAID
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT TeamBID, COUNT(GameID) AS Cnt
                      FROM Game
                      WHERE TeamBID = Winner
                      GROUP BY TeamBID
                      ORDER BY TeamBID
                     ) AS TB ON TB.TeamBID = Game.TeamAID
           GROUP BY TeamAID
          ) AS GP ON GP.TeamAID = Game.TeamAID

GROUP BY TeamAID
```

Comment: Two notes - first, in your second left join, you've got `TB.TeamBID = Game.TeamAID`. Second, it appears team #23 never wins a game while as Team A; you need to handle the "zero" case for each block.

Comment: I would do this using `ISNULL(TA.Cnt, 0)` if it were SQL Server, but it appears `ISNULL` doesn't take a replacement value parameter in mysql.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that team #11 never wins as TeamB and team #23 never wins as TeamA. The SQL version of 'ISNULL' would solve the issue but the MySQL version doesn't work the same way. Is there any other way to handle the case where the team just doesn't win? (sorry I'm still new to MySQL and I am still learning)

Comment: After some research into `ISNULL` I've come across the MySQL version of this function: [IFNULL](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-null-function.php) which solves the problem. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: No problem! If you've got time, you should write up your solution and post it below in case other people run across the same issue.